# Preventing PySide from Outrunning Python

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyside

I have a PySide application that connects a number of buttons to a function call that spins off a bunch of external processes (this isn't ideal, but it is necessary).

The function call takes less than a quarter of a second to run, but it still presents a chance for the user to outrun my code, causing lag, freezing, or crashing.

This leads me to a few questions...

1. What exactly does it mean for a callable to be connected to a signal? Suppose button A's click signal is connected a Python function f. If A is clicked, and then clicked again before f exits, does PySide simply queue another call to f, or does it do something fancier?
2. One possible solution is to make f disconnect itself from the signal and then reconnect before it exits. Before I go off rewriting things to try this, does anyone know if this is at all efficient, or if there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it does exactly what every other GUI toolkit does, which is try to execute that function for every button press. If you don't want that, then there are several approaches you can take:

1. Disable the button until the function finishes
2. Use a sentinel value, like self.running, and add a check to see if it is True. If so, return. Otherwise, set it to True and execute. Just remember to set it back to False at the end of the function
3. Do what you mentioned and disconnect the function from the signal

Those are the main ones. I'm sure there are some more esoteric solutions out there too though.